# rspec: undefined local variable or method `be_true'

Tags: rspec, cucumber, bundler, rspec2, rspec-expectations

I am using rspec 2.4.0 and cucumber 0.6.4.  I am running a simple scenario (for the sake of this question):

```
Scenario: Simple Test
When I test something
```

with step definition:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/expectations'

When /^I test something$/ do
  result = (1==1)
  result.should be_true
end
```

When I run this scenario I get the following problems:

```
 undefined local variable or method `be_true' for #<Object:0x1b3b424> (NameError)
```

I am also using bundler to manage my dependencies.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Regards,

Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the cucumber documentation:

> To use RSpec’s 2.x.x expectations (should), make sure the following is
>   in features/support/env.rb:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
World(RSpec::Matchers)
```

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/RSpec-Expectations