# cucumber: RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected true to respond to `true?`

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rspec-expectations

According the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760528/rspec-undefined-local-variable-or-method-be-true) I can use the `rspec` expectation form with the [cucumber](/questions/tagged/cucumber).

```
value = true
expect(value).to be_a(TrueClass) # => true
```

but if I use `#be_true` method it refused answering with exception:

```
expect(true).to be_true # => RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected true to respond to `true?`
```

So I can't use the method like I've used it in `rails` but without `rails` itself. So question is how can I add the methods not including the `rails`, and not defining them manually?

Comment: use `be_truthy` instead `be_true`

Comment: @Зелёный but in rails i've used exatly `be_true` =)

Comment: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/283

Comment: `be_true` works proper if in object defined method like `def true?;true;end`

Comment: @Зелёный I know, I can redefine it. but I wish not to do that, `I.expect(it).to be_worky` =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
expect(true).to be true
```

Although the RSpec documentation indicates `be_true` will pass if the object is not `nil` or `false`, in practice I find it does not pass if the object is `true`. If you want to check that the value is `true` specifically, and not just a truthy value, you need to use `be true`, (with the space), `eql true`, `eq true`, `equal true`, etc.

(If you're not already familiar, you can read about the difference between RSpec's equality matchers [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers). You don't say which RSpec version you're using, so that applies to 3.2 and I believe this is the same for other versions.)

Comment: This also requires the code change. I believe it is better to use be_truthy

Comment: Oh! Thank you for pointing that out. In that case, yes, if you're looking for any truthy value then `be_truthy` is better.